# An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, sql-server

Error I get:

> An exception of type `'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'` occurred in `System.Data.dll` but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Invalid object name `sp_VehicleInfo`.

Code:

```
protected void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        VehicleInfo vehicle = new VehicleInfo();
        vehicle.VehicleNo = txtVehicleNo.Text;
        vehicle.Make = txtMake.Text;
        vehicle.Model = txtEmail.Text;
        vehicle.Variety = txtVersion.Text;
        //vehicle.isAc = radAC.Text;
        vehicle.EngineNo = TextBox1.Text;
        vehicle.LExpDate = txtLicenseExpDate.Text;
        vehicle.InsuranceNo = TextBox2.Text;
        vehicle.IExpDate = txtInsuranceExpDate.Text;
        vehicle.Insert(); 
}
```

and this is the stored procedure

```
[dbo].[sp_VehicleInfo]              
    @VehicleNo NVARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @Make NVARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @Model NVARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @Variety NVARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @isAc BIT = NULL,
    @EngineNo NVARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @LExpDate NVARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @InsuranceNo NVARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @IExpDate NVARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @VehicleId bigint = NULL,
    @mode NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    IF(@mode = 'insert')
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO sp_VehicleInfo (VehicleNo, Make, Model, Variety, isAc, EngineNo, LExpDate, InsuranceNo, IExpDate)
        OUTPUT inserted.VehicleNo
        VALUES (@VehicleNo, @Make, @Model, @Variety, @isAc, @EngineNo, @LExpDate, @InsuranceNo, @IExpDate)
    END

    IF(@mode = 'update')
    BEGIN
        UPDATE sp_VehicleInfo
        SET VehicleNo = Isnull(@VehicleNo, VehicleNo),
            Make = Isnull(@Make, Make),
            Model = Isnull(@Model, Model),
            Variety = Isnull(@Variety, Variety),
            isAc = Isnull(@isAc, isAc),
            EngineNo = Isnull(@EngineNo, EngineNo),
            LExpDate = Isnull(@LExpDate, LExpDate),
            InsuranceNo = Isnull(@InsuranceNo, InsuranceNo),
            IExpDate = Isnull(@IExpDate, IExpDate)
        WHERE 
            VehicleId = @VehicleId
    END

    IF(@mode = 'get' )
    BEGIN
        SELECT * 
        FROM sp_VehicleInfo 
        WHERE VehicleId = @VehicleId
    END

    IF(@mode = 'delete') 
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM sp_VehicleInfo  
        WHERE VehicleId = @VehicleId
    END
END
```

Comment: What's the inner exception?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0):

This is a common error message. You are trying to access `sp_VehicleInfo` somewhere in your code and it seems like it is not a valid object in your database. From the naming convention you followed, I suppose it is a stored procedure. Check your database if this object is available or not.

Please note the following:

1. It may not be a good way to start a database object's name with "sp_" as system stored procedures follows that naming convention.
2. Please include all the code relevant to your question like the code that accesses the database in the post